# How to enhance the life of my weight gainer?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-gain

i have been taking weight gainers for last two months and gone from 66 kg to 74 kg.
But the problem is in india, they are pretty costly e.g. muscle tech mass tech 22 lbs costs 150 US Dollar after discount.
5 scoups a day adds 2000 calories to my daily intake.
But i can not afford it any more.
How should i take it to so that at least it remains there for two months.

Comment: In order to make it last for 60 days, take the remaining powder, and divide it up into 60 equal portions, and that is your daily budget.

Answer (score 2):

```
G O M A D
A F I   A
L   L   Y
L   K
O
N
```

Use WHOLE MILK.

Drink 1 GALLON per day.

```
serving size 1 gal (4 kg)
total calories 2407 | % daily value^*
total fat 129 g     | 198%
saturated fat 81 g  | 403%
protein 129 g       | 257%
```

*percent daily values are based on a 2000 calorie diet
(averaged over different types of whole milk)

Lots of protein, lots of calories, does the same thing mass gainer does at a fraction of the cost.

Comment: I do not know, but it +1 for the simple technique

Answer (score 1):

Weight gainers are not special. They are just really calorically dense supplements with a very specific macro distribution. So if you look at say, the Optimum Nutrition Pro Gainer nutrients you can see this:

[image]

As you can see there's lots of protein, lots of carbohydrates, a little fat, and lots of calories for one serving.

What you can do instead is replace the weight gainer with foods that are far cheaper. I don't know what kinds of foods are easily available in India, so it is hard to make suggestions. You would want to look for things that are high in carbs and protein. You can mix and match foods. You don't have to have it in one serving, so it can be spread out through the whole day.